# Is there any downside to constantly creating and disconnecting consumers from a kafka topic?

Tags: apache-kafka

Is there any downside to constantly creating and disconnecting consumers from a kafka topic? For example, if I were to create a consumer and subscribe to a kafka topic, then disconnect this consumer. Then create a new consumer and subscribe to the same topic, then disconnect it, and repeat this process.

Comment: Is your consumer in a group ?  What's your senario of repeating this process ?